# Access Objects from another class?

Tags: java, object

I am currently on my way to learning java. And im making a tiny card game like hearthstone for experimental purposes :)

But ive run into a issue. Im creating all the cards/"minions" in another class to keep this all looking good.

The problem is that i cant access them from any other class like the main class..

Here is the Minion Class:

```
  package project.main;

public class Minion {

    private int ID;
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private String disc;
    private int health;
    private int attack;
    private int cost;


    public Minion(int minionID, String minionName, String minionType,  String minionDisc, int minionHealth, int minionAttack, int minionCost)
    {
        ID = minionID;
        name = minionName;
        type = minionType;
        disc = minionDisc;
        health = minionHealth;
        attack = minionAttack;
        cost = minionCost;

    }

    public void displayMinionData() {

        System.out.println("ID: " + ID);
        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
        System.out.println("Type: " + type);
        System.out.println("Discription: " + disc);
        System.out.println("Health: " + health);
        System.out.println("Attack: " + attack);
        System.out.println("Cost: " + cost);


       }

    }
```

And here is the MinionTracker class (Where i create the objects):

```
    package project.main;

public class MinionTracker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Minion Soldier = new Minion(0, "Soldier", "Human", "The First minion", 2, 1, 1);

    }

}
```

And i want to access that soldier on the main class. But i have no idea how to. Any answer would be really helpful!!

Comment: Simply `Soldier.displayMinionData();` inside your `main`?

Comment: It is a bad practice starting variable names by an upper case.

Comment: @zuaxis did u understand how to solve your issue?

Comment: @Kick Buttowski Indeed i did. I completely missed the point. Thank you so much for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

**Some hints or advice about your code that help you :**

**1**. try to define your setter and getters for encapsulation purposes ,and having access to each field.

for example:

```
private int ID;
```

**getter method** is

```
public int getID(){
       return this.ID;
  }
```

**setter method** is

```
public void setID(int newID){
       this.ID = newID;
 }
```

**2**. Instead of having  `displayMinionData()` , it is good practice to override `toString` method

For example if your variables are :

```
   private String came;
   private String city;

   public String toString(){
         return name + " " + city;
   }
```

I am not sure what you by accessing the solider in main method:

but you have this

```
Minion soldier = new Minion(0, "Soldier", "Human", "The First minion", 2, 1, 1);
```

As I told you

> **1**.  you can **printout** the whole info by using overridden **toString** on the console
>
> **2**.  you can **extract** each portion of the soldier variable by **using getters**
>
> **3**.  you can **update** each portion of the soldier variable by **using setters**

sample for toString:

```
System.out.print("Info about the current soldier is " + soldier.toString());
```

sample for getters:

```
System.out.println("ID:" + soldier .getID()):
```

sample for setters:

```
   int newID = 123456789;
   soldier.setID(newID);
   System.out.println("The new id of current soldier is " + soldier.getID()):
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access individual fields (such as `name`, `health`, `attack`, etc) you will have to add public access for them. By declaring them private, you made them only visible inside the Minion class. That's not a bad thing! It's best practice to keep fields private, but provide public getters / setters to get or set the values, respectively. This ensures they can't be changed except by specific methods that you have written.

To write a getter/setters, make two methods for each field which needs public visibility:

```
public int getID(){
    return this.ID;
}

public void setID(int ID){
    this.ID = ID;
}
```

Then, you can create a Minion (as you have) and do something like `System.out.println(soldier.getName());`

(By the way, it's convention in Java to capitalize classes (like `Minion` and `MinionTracker`) and camelCase objects (like `soldier` or `minionName`)

Comment: So like what i did before making that soldier object. How do i put all of these variables together as one in the end? Can you make a whole example on how you make a object then? @Daniel

Comment: What do you mean by 'put all of these variables together as one in the end'? They are already together, inside your Minion class.

Comment: Im not sure how to put it. Im very new. But now ive made the setters and getters of Minion, i want to create a new instance of minion, with its own ID, name and so on. I dont know exactly how to put it @Daniel

Comment: What i meant was that i want to create a minion like before, called soldier. with that title, attack, health and so on @Daniel

Comment: Oh i got it. I just made a bad mistake. But i got it

Comment: `Minion soldier = new Minion(0, "Soldier", "Human", "The First minion", 2, 1, 1);` creates the soldier object with the given parameters. To use it, call `soldier.whatevermethod`. When you need another minion, just call `Minion stonetuskBoar = new Minion(1, "Stonetusk Boar", "Beast", "Charge", 1, 1, 1);`

Comment: I would like to thank you. Sorry i didnt get the last part. I completely lost the point. But thank you so much for the help :) @Daniel